# ЕГЭ, Python "Построение алгоритмов и практические вычисления"

Tags: python

Само задание:

Автомат обрабатывает натуральное число N (0 ≤ N ≤ 255) по следующему алгоритму:

1. Строится восьмибитная двоичная запись числа N.
2. Все цифры двоичной записи заменяются на противоположные (0 на 1, 1 на 0).
3. Полученное число переводится в десятичную запись.
4. Из нового числа вычитается исходное, полученная разность выводится на экран.
   Какое число нужно ввести в автомат, чтобы в результате получилось 111?

Пожалуйста объясните, что я сделал не так.

```py
def f(N):
    n = bin(N)[2:]
    n = str.maketrans('01', '10')
    return int(n, 2)

for N in range (1, 255):
    if f(N) == 111:
        print(N)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `maketrans` делает таблицу преобразования, само преобразование делается через `translate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли вычислить разность `Из нового числа вычитается исходное, полученная разность`

Кроме того, строки там вообще не нужны, биты можно инвертировать с помощью оператора "исключающего или" - xor (`^`). Вся функция:

```
def f(N):
    n = N ^ 255
    return N - n
```